# Dicionario dentro de outro

Tags: python-3.x

Olá, estou com um problema e gostaria de uma solução. Eu quero adicionar um dicionario dentro de um outro dicionario, porém eu não estou conseguindo... Eu tentei usar o append e nada. Alguém me ajuda!

```
dicionario1 = {"Estado": "São Paulo}
dicionario2 = {}
```

Quero colocar o dicionario 1 dentro do 2 mas não sei como.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `append` não existe na classe `dict()`. O que você pode fazer é utilizar uma chave dentro de colchetes no primeiro dicionário e depois atribuir o outro dicionário a essa chave.

```
dicionario["<chave>"] = outro_dicionario
```

Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
registros = {}

usuario1 = {"Nome": "Antônio", "Idade": 27}
usuario2 = {"Nome": "Maria", "Idade": 23}

registros["Pessoa1"] = usuario1
registros["Pessoa2"] = usuario2
```